# Using HTML without <>

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Is there a way to do:

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

Without using " <> " ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you that you can use Jade! Take a look at this [link](http://html2jade.org/)

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
 head
  title Jade
  script(type='text/javascript').
  alert(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is *Jade*  [Jade examples @](https://www.sitepoint.com/jade-tutorial-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

There is not, unless you'd use some sort of processing library.